# Nginx and proxy to avoid Flex security error

Tags: apache-flex, url, nginx

When doing a snapshot with flex bipmapdata.draw() a security error is raised if the image does not come from an allowed domain.

I am trying to add images from several urls sources (google image) therefore i can't call draw().

If however the image is frow my server www.foo.com which has a nice crossdomain.xml its all good.

My question related to Nginx is the following:

How can i make a proxy where http://www.foo.com/img_proxy/bar_img_url will fecth the image from http://bar_img_url and return it as if it come from **www.foo.com** domain.

So far i used:

```
location /img_proxy/ {
    rewrite  ^/img_proxy/(.*)  http://$1  last;
}
```

It does the job of fetching the image but somehow flex still knows its not coming from my server since .draw() still fails.

I wish i could see through the http headers sent by flash.

How would you solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: For now it returns a 302 HTTP/1.x 302 Moved Temporarily, how can i make it returns the image instead ?

Comment: Add some header rules after rewrite. Actually, I'd rather use proxy_pass